# XMLHttpRequest responseXML is always null

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, web-services, debugging

I am calling a asmx web service like this

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }      
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            var data = xmlhttp.responseText;
            var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://Service/ServiceName.asmx/method?query=data1&count=1",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.send();
```

even after the readystate being 4, I get responseXML as null and responseText as empty. whereas the url

```
"https://Service/ServiceName.asmx/method?query=data1&count=1"
```

works perfectly in the browser.

Please help.

Comment: And the service is of course on the same domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: I changed the code to implement CORS, but still same problem...

Comment: i can't make changes to server side code, what change needs to be done to make cross origin calls...

Comment: How about a java component, or AIR, or thin-client?

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path:

```
with(new XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  open("GET","/Service/ServiceName.asmx/method?query=data1&count=1",true);
  setRequestHeader("Foo", "Bar");
  send("");
  onreadystatechange = handler;
  }

function handler(event)
 {
 !!event.target && !!event.target.readyState && event.target.readyState === 4 && ( console.log(event) );
 }
```

If that doesn't work, try loading the URL from JavaScript to check for routing issues:

```
 window.location = "/Service/ServiceName.asmx/method?query=data1&count=1"
```